# why wont my script work when i test it with postman

Tags: javascript

when i text my code in JavaScript with postman there was error

the index code is :

```
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const patient = require("./routes/patient");
const express = require("express")
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app =express()
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use("/", patient);

 

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/DataStore", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
 
  
});
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("working on 3000 port");
  });



app.get("/", (req, res) => {

   
 
});
```

the patient.js is :

```
    const experss = require("express");
const Route = experss.Router();
const Patient = require("../modules/patient");

Route.post("/addpatient", (req, res) => {
    const patient = new Patient({
        patientId: req.body.patientId,
        patientName: req.body.patientName,
        patientage: req.body.patientage,
        patientMumName: req.body.patientMumName,
        patientfatherid: req.body.patientfatherid,
        createdAt: req.body.createdAt,
     
    });

    Patient.create(Patient)
        .then((result) => {
        res.status(201).json({
        message: "done with adding",
        data: result,
         });
    })

       .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err,
         });
       });
    
}); 

Route.get("/getPatient/", (req, res) => {
  // Patient.find({})
  //   .then((data) => {
  //     if (data) {
  //       res.json(data);
  //     } else {
  //       res.json("nothig to show");
  //     }
  //   })
  //   .catch((err) => res.send({ error: "Nothing fonddddd" }));
  res.send("done");
});


Route.put("/updatePatient/:id", (req, res) => {

  Patient.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
    $set: {  
    
      patientName: req.body.patientName,
      patientage: req.body.patientage,
      patientMumName: req.body.patientMumName,
      patientfatherid: req.body.patientfatherid,
      
    },
  }).then(() => {
    Patient.findOne({ StuId: req.body.id }).then((data) => {
      res.send(data);
    });
  });
});

Route.delete("/DeletePatient/:id", (req, res) => {
  Patient.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id).then(() => {
    res.send("Done with delete");
  });
});











module.exports = Route;
```

the error was:

> Error
>
> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
>             
>     at C:\Users\nsr\Desktop\clinic\routes\patient.js:21:9
>             
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\nsr\Desktop\clinic\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>             
>     at next (C:\Users\nsr\Desktop\clinic\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>             
>     at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\nsr\Desktop\clinic\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>             
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\nsr\Desktop\clinic\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>             
>     at C:\Users\nsr\Desktop\clinic\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
>             
>     at Function.process_params (C:\Users\nsr\Desktop\clinic\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:341:12)
>             
>     at next (C:\Users\nsr\Desktop\clinic\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>             
>     at Function.handle (C:\Users\nsr\Desktop\clinic\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
>             
>     at router (C:\Users\nsr\Desktop\clinic\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
> ```

Comment: The error is in `patient.js` so please post the code of that file.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli 
i update the question

Comment: Re edit, so it says that the return value of `Patient.create(Patient)
` is `undefined` so we still don't have a [mcve]. (You should probably remove all the web server code and make a simple test script to debug this with).

Comment: sorry but I don't understand @GabrielePetrioli

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is with  `Patient.create(Patient)`

It should be `Patient.create(patient)` (*lowercase `patient` as param, which is the one you created a couple lines above*)

Comment: thankyou very much that's right the problem was with the letter P

Answer (score 1):

As Gabriele pointed out the error seems to be the capital cased `Patient` instead of `patient`. Alternatively, here's a another solution using async-await:

```js
Route.post("/addpatient", async (req, res) => {
    const patient = new Patient({
        patientId: req.body.patientId,
        patientName: req.body.patientName,
        patientage: req.body.patientage,
        patientMumName: req.body.patientMumName,
        patientfatherid: req.body.patientfatherid,
        createdAt: req.body.createdAt,
     
    });
    try {
      const result = await Patient.create(patient);
      return res.status(201).json({
        message: "done with adding",
        data: result,
      });
    } catch(err){
       return res.status(500).json({
        error: err,
       });
    }
    
});
```